# Absolute element height and width 100% on mobile with desktop site view

Tags: html, css, mobile, height, desktop

Is there a way to set an absolute positioned element to cover whole screen on a mobile browser with enabled desktop site view?

My app consists of some absolute positioned elements that are covering the whole screen (width - 100% and height 100%) so I can change them by simply sliding one out and one in. It is wokring perfectly fine both on desktop and mobile browser but when I enable desktop site view on mobile the body element is still covering the whole screen while the absolute elements are much more smaller.
It looks like this

[image]

I was testing it on mobile chrome browser and I am using similar css rules to this page: https://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ and it also has the same problem.

Is it possible to make it really 100% wide and high?

Here is the simplest html showing my problem

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100vw;
  }
  body {
   background-color: #AAA;
  }
  .phaseScreen{ 
   width:100vw;
   height:100vh;
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='phaseScreen'>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result on my chrome mobile looks like this[image]

Comment: Supply code, we have no idea what is happening without it

Comment: Maybe I misundestand your question, but did you try 100vh and 100vw instead of percent?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$("#trigger").click(function() {
  if (!$("#slide").hasClass("slide-in")) {
    $("#slide").addClass("slide-in");
  } else {
    $("#slide").removeClass("slide-in");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  margin: 0;
}

#slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  left: -100%;
  transition: .2s left ease-in-out;
}

.slide-in {
  left: 0 !important;
}

#trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: .5rem;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="slide">
    <h1>Hello this is a headline</h1>
    <p>This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. This is some content. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="trigger">click me</div>
</body>
```